Aiogram при нажатии кнопки в отдельной группе "Квитанции" человеку должен выдаваться товар. Но этого не происходит
В общем делаю бота для продажи услуг либо какого то контента.
Проблема заключается в том, что, если человек оплачивает то квитанция, которую он скинул в бота идет мне в группу "Квитанции" там то я уже и подтверждаю перевод, но товар не выдается... Что делать? Если будет нужно покажу полный код


Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.
